# CISCO Router Interface Coomands

Tags: interface, command, cisco

I am reading book 'CCNA Routing and Switiching  Study Guide - Lammle, Todd' wherein there was a command  to create an interface (int f0/0).

On CISCO Router command when I am giving a command
`Corp(Config)#int f0/0`

It is displaying error message as "**Invalid interface type and number**". Please help me with this command.

Comment: You don't create fast ethernet interfaces. FE interfaces are physical entities and as such they can't be created or destroyed via software, you can just configure them. As the message says, you're trying to configure something that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on **packet tracer** or **gns3**, go to the arrow on the router to show interface name. Or you can write this command:

```
corp # show ip interface brief
```

to find out the interfaces available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your router doesn't have a module with a port named ' int f0/0 ' , turn off the router in your simulator (Packet tracer, GNS3..) and try to add a module wish have a port with 'int f0/0' ,otherwise, try to understand which port type and number your router has.

Tyr this command in ur CLI: ***show ip interface brief*** if it doesn't show u nothing try this '***do show ip interface brief***'

Answer (score 0):

when you are in global configuration mode type

hit this coomand:

> > do show ip int brief
> >
> > Ip int (put the interface name) and configure it

Answer (score 0):

Well its totally depends on your router's module name...First check the module name by using command  **show ip interface brief in privilege mode..**  if your router have module with f0/0 then only router will enter interface f0/0..